# How are multiple applications able to use the same CPU registers?

Tags: x86, cpu, cpu-registers

At university this past semester, we played around with x86 assembly- learning how to move memory into registers, playing with the instruction sets, and doing a bit of reverse engineering with binary bombs.

But this got me thinking, if I can write a program which can move memory into the EAX register, what if another program wants to use the EAX register, too? Computers execute droves of instructions under multiple processes nowadays- how is the value that I write in a particular register saved when another process wants to use that register as well? Is it moved to RAM? Into caches?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch

Comment: Context is saved in RAM by the kernel.  Memory is cacheable, so the kernel might have a cache hit when restoring the context if it wasn't evicted.